Skglm: Linearily combining SCAD penalty with Ridge penalty
I am fitting the following penalized SCAD regression model using the skglm library. However, a pure SCAD penalty is not really stable in the case of high correlation among the regressors which is the case in the dataset I am using. Is there a way to combine the SCAD penalty with the RIDGE penalty using a linear combination controlled by a hyperparameter as in an Elastic Net regression using the following code?
import skglm
from skglm.penalties import SCAD
from skglm import GeneralizedLinearEstimator
import numpy as np

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Define dimensions
num_samples = 300
num_features = 10000

# Generate X with random values
X = np.random.randn(num_samples, num_features)

# Generate y with random values
y = np.random.randn(num_samples, 1)

# SCAD penalty
scad_penalty = SCAD(alpha=1,gamma=3.7)

# Create a generalized linear regressor with SCAD penalty
model = GeneralizedLinearEstimator(penalty=scad_penalty)
test_fit=model.fit(X,y)

